# How can I define a tuple array with different tuple types explicitly in typescript?

Tags: typescript, tuples

I'm writing a converter that converts a tuple array into an object using a lookup object that tells the function which strings map to which properties. However, I can't find a way to tell typescript that it's an array of tuples with specific types, the resulting tuples are always unions. Here's how it looks like:

```
interface EndObj {
    a: number; 
    b: string;
    c?: number;
}
interface InitObj {
    d: string;
    e: string;
    f: string;
}

const map = {
    d: 'a',
    e: 'b',
    f: 'c'
} as const;

type MapType = typeof map;
type ResultTuple<T extends keyof InitObj> = [T, EndObj[MapType[T]]];
type ResultTupleArray = ResultTuple<keyof InitObj>[];

const resultObj: ResultTupleArray = [['d', 1], ['e', 3], ['f', 3]]; // invalid! the value of 'e' should only allow strings
```

I think the reason why typescript allows this is, because `ResultTupleArray` is defined with `keyof InitObj`, so the resulting tuple array generic is always the same, so `T` will always be the same instead of specific per array entry, thus it can only be described with a union.

Here's how I found it out:

```
const undetected: ResultTuple<keyof InitObj> = ['e', 4]; // should be invalid
const detected: ResultTuple<'e'> = ['e', 4]; // actually shows an error for 4 (Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.)
```

For a bit of context, here's how the converter looks like:

```
function mapInitToEnd(resultO: ResultTupleArray) {
    const endObj: EndObj = {
        a: -1,
        b: ''
    };

    for (const tuple of resultO) {
        const [key, val] = tuple;
        const mappedKey = map[key];
        endObj[mappedKey] = val;
    }
    return endObj;
}
```

Is there a way to tell typescript that the generic is only valid per entry in the tuple array, and not for the full array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to distribute your `ResultTuple` definition so that if `T` is a union of keys, then the result is a union of tuples.  The easiest way to accomplish this given your code is to make the definition a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), which gives you this behavior for free:

```
type ResultTuple<T extends keyof InitObj> = T extends any ? [T, EndObj[MapType[T]]] : never;
```

Distributive conditional types kick in when you have `T extends U ? X : Y` where `T` is a type parameter.  So to get this to happen above we add the otherwise-useless `T extends any ? ... : never` check.  Now your code will give you the error you expect:

```
const resultObj: ResultTupleArray = [['d', 1], ['e', 3], ['f', 3]];  // error!
// number not assignable to string ----------> ~~~~~~~~
```

There are other ways to get this behavior; for instance, by building a [mapped type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and immediately [looking up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) its properties:

```
type ResultTuple<T extends keyof InitObj> = { [K in T]: [K, EndObj[MapType[K]]] }[T];
```

Either way should work.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIgCYHkBGArZAbwChkzk4AuZEAVwFsdoBuU8nagZzClAHNW5ZAgD81OoxbEAvsmKhIsRCgCSIYGFwESQjFx79B5CPt4gBbMjFOGZxYggD2IbsnpwADsgC8RS8j1kAHI4IIAafxNgnHD-a2CEIJkKTmFnblZiMABPDxQAWU8AFVyUXxy8xxg3T1YKlAAlCE5aABswItoPVogAHiLkCAAPSExUgGsIbKrkNQ0tAD4fZAHh0YxUuBBs5BFkAG0isLRMLX3CjxK8w4BdO+RxCAA3KXrkJpb2zu6IAEEoKBwHa+D5tDpdHq9SbTapzTT4Bb7G6ZJwuMDIKDNMFaaigr4Qv4AoHLfb7IIYcLIACMN2OZIglIAzLSDkEYEy7swyAB6bmDAGOKAAQmIvJoDCYUBojnRcE4nGAfBAcBwPWQYEcyG4Zj4yAAtAbDUalgA-M3ms32ZX0ZoeZTIX6tTiakj+N4XK5ldWlGbuDxGMhvPHgn79QYjCBjZDQmZwxbLQgHADSyFAKxu1H2SeO6Gw+HOxVKWbuN2Q0luAe9eXeWPxP3+gOBNc+IchMdh6nheERyPsQlRrkxLZxzbB3x6DeJvlJ5MpNLpQQZx2ZC-Zy85PL50CggpFQjFEkl0tl8sVytVKA1WoM5n1Rvvpot5pkQA)

Comment: very detailled explanation, i need to spend some time to comprehend this. however, while this works for the `resultObj` array, it doesn't work for the converter function when trying to assign the `endObj` property. what's the reason for that?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "doesn't work"?  I'm assuming you are talking about some compiler error inside the implementation of `mapInitToEnd()`, but that would be a separate issue having to do with TypeScript's lack of support for [correlated record types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

Comment: yep, that's exactly what i meant. thanks for the insight!